# What's the difference between "PriorityMux" and "MuxCase" in chisel3

Tags: scala, chisel

It seems that the first value associated with the high enable signal will be returned, no matter in using PriorityMux or MuxCase.

So what's the difference between them?

MuxCase:

[image]

PriorityMux:

[image]

Comment: MuxCase have default value.